# Storing images in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it good idea to store images in Kafka in JSON field as byte code?

```
{
   id: 1,
   images: [bytecode]
}
```

I think about that because Kafka allows a partitiona and replications.

I ask this because I need analysis of coming images and getting real time result

Comment: best to keep image in some where e.g. AWS S3 and keep image location in Kafka topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on many aspects - for example the image size, client performance for encoding / decoding the images from JSON etc. One way how this is often implemented is to just keep a link to something like S3 storage in the message instead of the binary. E.g.

```
{
   id: 1,
   images: ["https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/puppy.jpg"]
}
```

Some object storage systems - such as for example Ceph even let you send notifications to Kafka automatically when new object is uploaded. So it would be for example enough to just upload the image there and it would send the notification to your Kafka topic.